# How to verify Swiftmailer credentials on Postfix

Tags: php, email, postfix, email-server

I'm using Swiftmailer with php to send emails over my Postfix server. It works fine. But also works without verifying the credentials specified on php. How can I verify in Postfix if those credentials are correct and then allow the mail sending?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should set up a dedicated submission listener on postfix that only allows authenticated submission.

Refer to the commented-out example in master.cf, and swicth submitting applications to port 587.